# Panel in a panel shows different textbox width

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

my winforms project contains some panels with textboxes, which all have the width 300. One of the panels contains another panel, but the textboxes of the inner panel look a lot larger. When I set the size of the inner panel exact what it was in its own designer, then it cuts off the textboxes. How can I get my textboxes to look the same size, no matter in what panel they are?
Best Regards, Expecto

Answer (score 0):

Have you explicitly set the width of your textboxes?

You can do this in one of three ways:

- In the Properties window when using the designer (select a textbox first).
- Set the TextBox.Width properties in the formName.Designer.cs file.
- Set the TextBox.Width properties explicitly in your code behind (`textBox1.Width = 300;`).

Comment: I have set it this way: `this.textBoxContactCountry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 24);`